# Creating a list view for custom objects

Tags: custom-object

My issue is that I don't know where to navigate in order to create a list view for a custom object. I've reviewed the documentation @ http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customviews.htm and searched "list view" on the setup screen in my sandbox.

How do I go about creating a listview/list of all items in salesforce for a custom object I have created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have a tab for the custom object in order to create list views for it. To create a  tab, go to Setup > Create > Tabs and add a new Custom Object Tab. You will also need to make sure the tab is visible to the profiles you want and added to their apps.